# How to get the correct date format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to get this date format in Snowflake?

```
"day; YYYY/MM/DD; HH:MM AM - HH:MM AM" format in snowflake
```

Tried these logic:

```
select current_date()
,to_char(DAY() , 'MMMM DD, YYYY')
,to_date (to_char(current_date() , 'MMMM DD, YYYY'), 'MMMM DD, YYYY')
;

select to_timestamp('2019-02-28 23:59:59.000000000 -07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
```

Comment: Can you provide an input date example and the expected output one?

Answer (score 0):

You question seems rather confused.

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2019-02-28 23:59:59.123400000 -07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
```

gives:

| TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-02-28 23:59:59.123400000 -07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') |
| --- |
| 2019-02-28 23:59:59.123 -0700 |

so it seems possible to parse the string to -> timestamp with timezone.

```
select 
    column1 as cd
    ,to_char(cd, 'MMMM DD, YYYY') as d1
    ,to_char(cd, 'DY; YYYY/MM/DD; HH:MI AM') as d2
FROM VALUES
    (current_date),
    (current_timestamp)
```

gives:

| CD | D1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 00:00:00.000 -0700 | April 07, 2022 | Thu; 2022/04/07; 00:00 AM |
| 2022-04-07 00:39:13.433 -0700 | April 07, 2022 | Thu; 2022/04/07; 00:39 AM |

### Full Day:

So as noted in the comments there are a couple ways to get Day of Week:

```
select 
    current_date() as cd
    ,extract ('dayofweek_iso',current_date()) as dow_1
    ,dayofweekiso(cd) as dow_2
    ,decode(dow_1, 1, 'Monday', 2, 'Tuesday', 3, 'Wednesday', 4, 'Thursday', 5, 'Friday', 6, 'Saturday', 7, 'Sunday') as full_day;
```

| CD | DOW_1 | DOW_2 | FULL_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 | 4 | 4 | Thursday |

### Full Output:

```
select 
    current_timestamp() as cd
    ,extract ('dayofweek_iso',current_date()) as dow_1
    ,dayofweekiso(cd) as dow_2
    ,decode(dow_1, 1, 'Monday', 2, 'Tuesday', 3, 'Wednesday', 4, 'Thursday', 5, 'Friday', 6, 'Saturday', 7, 'Sunday') as full_day
    ,full_day || to_char(cd, '; YYYY/MM/DD; HH:MI AM -  HH:MI AM') as full_format;
```

gives:

| CD | DOW_1 | DOW_2 | FULL_DAY | FULL_FORMAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 14:57:11.717 -0700 | 4 | 4 | Thursday | Thursday; 2022/04/07; 14:57 PM - 14:57 PM |

Comment: select decode(extract ('dayofweek_iso',current_date()),
  1, 'Monday',
  2, 'Tuesday',
  3, 'Wednesday',
  4, 'Thursday',
  5, 'Friday',
  6, 'Saturday',
  7, 'Sunday');

Comment: If I want to display the day name, say for example: Monday, I can use this logic right?

Comment: My question is - I want to display the date like this -- "Wednesday; YYYY/MM/DD; HH:MM AM - HH:MM AM"

Comment: Yes you mention the "format you want to use" but the problem with using "format notation" is , "you formatting is not valid" so it does not communicate what you want the output to look like.